# UIVisualEffect is not showing on UIView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview

I have a `UIView` and that a create programmatically, then I added as a `subView` to my `viewController.view`. However, The view is not affected with the blur.
Here is my code:

```
let blurryView: UIView = {
    let blur = UIView()
    blur.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    blur.alpha = 0.90
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .extraLight)
    let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blur.addSubview(blurEffectView)
    blurEffectView.center = blur.center
    blurEffectView.frame = blur.bounds
    blur.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return blur
}()

func manageBlurView() {
    blurryView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250).isActive = true
    blurryView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250).isActive = true
    blurryView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    blurryView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubview(blurryView)
    manageBlurView()

}
```

- The blur effect is added and I doubled checked that using `breakpoints` and pint statements `if blur.subviews == [blurEffectView] {
          print("Blur effect added as a subview")
      }` and it printed.
- I have a background image to make sure if it's blurred.
- I also tried to add the blur effect in the `viewDidLoad()`, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add both the yellow background view and the blurred view directly as child of your main view :

```
    let backg = UIView(frame: self.view.frame)
    backg.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    backg.alpha = 0.90

    self.view.addSubview(backg)

    // the blur effect
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .extraLight)
    let blurredEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)

    blurredEffectView.frame = self.view.frame
    self.view.addSubview(blurredEffectView)
```

You could put the above code in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Thank you for you help. I don't know why I should do it this way. I'm dealing with constraints so I can easily re-constraint things and move them around.